# Braintree integration with an Android Eclipse Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, braintree

I have been trying to integrate the Braintree SDK to my Eclipse project to develop a chained payment system on my app , however I have found that their SDK works with only Android Studio and they do not support Eclipse , so is thee a way in which I can import their SDK to my Eclipse project ? Help would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this for the last 4 weeeks now :(

Cheers,
Varun

Comment: have you checked this https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/android

Answer (score 2):

The Braintree android SDK definitely supports eclipse, there shouldn't be anything that requires android studio. In fact, the Braintree documentation does have a section about getting the SDK setup with Eclipse. Did you try following these instructions?

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+ruby/sdk/client/setup#downloading-manually

That section should outline how to do it, and it should work just like any other library you would use in android. If you still have issues with those instructions let me know the specific errors you see and I can try to help.